# Error messase for part of the query:Either list of columns or a custom serializer should be specified

Tags: mysql, sql

i am doing something wrong in this section of the query file:

```
    CREATE TABLE LR_Charts;
    INSERT INTO TABLE LR_Charts 
    select campid,CampNum,Count,Legend from tmp_LRchart1 Order By CampNum;

    ALTER TABLE LR_Charts ADD COLUMNS (CountCumm  INT);


    Select tmp_LRchart1.campid, tmp_LRchart1.Count, SUM(LR_Charts.Count) 
    as LR_Charts.CountCumm from tmp_LRchart1, LR_Charts 
    where tmp_LRchart1.campid >= LR_Charts.campid 
    group by tmp_LRchart1.campid order by tmp_LRchart1.campid;
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
CREATE TABLE LR_Charts;
```

is wrong.

You are trying to create table without specifying list of columns for it.
It should be like:

```
CREATE TABLE LR_Charts( i int, v varchar(10) );
```

---

But looking at your statements what I understood is that,
you are trying to create a table with data from another table.
If that is right, then your query should be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE LR_Charts AS  
select campid,CampNum,Count,Legend from tmp_LRchart1 Order By CampNum;
```